# Not receiving dynamically generated form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

i am creating a form through php html and ajax that is specific for each row of a database table.  I send the form data through ajax to another page which then takes that form data and uses it to pull data from another database based upon the results given and displays them.

I am fairly sure the problem is either with my select statement on the recipedisplay.php page or my syntax is wrong on how to echo out a returned variable.

select.php

```
<?php <script>
$('.button').click(function (e){
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pages/recipes/recipedisplay.php',
    data: $('#f'+id).serialize(),
    success: function(d){
       $('#infodisplay').html(d);
    }
});
});
</script>



<div id=\"a".$row['id']."\">

        <form id=\"f" . $row['id'] . "\">

    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"recipeid\" id=\"recipeid\" value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">


    <div id=\"reciperesultbutton\"  class=\"button\"><div id=\"centering\">" . $row['name'] ." </div></div>
    <div id=\"reciperesulttext\"> " . $row['id'] ." " . $row['longdesc'] ."</div>
    </form>
    <br>
    </div>

";
}

?>
```

recipedisplay.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['recipeid']);


$sql= "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE 'id' ='".$id."'";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$name = $row['name'];
$longdesc = $row['longdesc'];



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

echo " fail ";     
echo " . $name . ";
};

echo " . $id . ";

echo " work "; 

echo " . $longdesc . ";
echo "$row[name]";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Try taking the quotes out from around id in your select statement in recipedisplay.php. So it looks like this `$sql= "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id ='".$id."'";`

Comment: There was no effect.  I've also tried echo "$_POST"; and it just displays the following text: ARRAY

Comment: You are using `$(this).attr('id')` on your `$('.button').click`, but your `<div id=\"reciperesultbutton\"  class=\"button\">` has an `id` of `reciperesultbutton`. So you are basically calling `$('#freciperesultbutton').serialize()` which does not exist

Comment: You should change your `select.php` structure disposing `html` and `javascript` code separately from `php`. Thereby to avoid escaping single(double) quotes everytime

Comment: You have a lot of non-dynamic `id`s in your code - `id=\"recipeid\" `, `id=\"reciperesultbutton\"`, `id=\"centering\,`id=\"reciperesulttext\"` - which is going to give you headaches going forward. These either need to be classes, or you need to add your `$row['id']` to make them unique.

Comment: @Sean I'm trying to send the value from the hidden input(which is generated from a db(this works)) the form id has to be unique since I am displaying multiple results to use thevariable id as the form id I need to add an alpha character, I used f.  The ajax calls for the id and adds the f.  I don't quite understand what you are seeing here

Comment: Its a one purpose page I am working on here, all I need from it is the unique id from the desired result.  I have had it working before but I had to roll back, I don't do version control beyond backing up every few days.

Comment: I understand that you want to submit the value of your `<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"recipeid\"`, but your issue is that you are not getting the correct `id` to submit the correct `<form id=\"f" . $row['id'] . "\">`. I am telling you the issue lies in `var id = $(this).attr('id');`. If you were to do an `alert(id)` you would see that it is not the value you think it is.

Comment: Alright, so I see what you mean that it is returning the reciperesultbutton but it loads to the next page.  Would the problem possibly be around

        data: $('#f'+id).serialize(),

Comment: The simplest solution would be to store the `$row['id']` in your `<div id=\"reciperesultbutton\"  class=\"button\">`, for example - `data-formid=\"".$row['id']."\"` -> `<div id=\"reciperesultbutton\" data-formid=\"".$row['id']."\" class=\"button\">`. Then you would just change `var id = $(this).attr('id');` to `var id = $(this).data('formid');`. Now your `$('#f'+id).serialize()` would work properly, as `id` would be a `$row['id']` value instead of `reciperesultbutton`

Comment: alright, so its displaying the echo of ". $id ." but its not displaying any of the other data associated with it. 

Something with the Select statement I think.  I've also tried Ahmeds solution to no avail

Comment: First thing I see is that your query has a syntax error - `$sql= "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE 'id' ='".$id."'";`. You need to remove the quotes around the `'id'`. It either needs to be without quotes - `id =` or with backticks - `\`id\` = `, as with quotes it is a string vs a column name.

Comment: tried it both ways with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

because mysqli_fetch_array() takes mysqli_query() result not your **$sql** query

So try to run your query first by this code :

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query);
```

Also you can use mysqli_fetch_assoc() that takes mysqli_query() too as a parameter

Comment: I just tried this and it seemingly had no effect.  Even when combined with sean's suggestions above

Comment: Try this code by copy and paste it


`$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE Id='".$id."'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);

$name = $row['name'];
$longdesc = $row['logndesc'];`


just try by copy and paste it